# Grails: Bootstrap.groovy Vs ServletContextListener

Tags: java, grails

I need to start some services on Application Startup & shut them down on application shut down.

Which one would be better way to do this..

1) bootstrap.groovy's init & destroy or

2) implement ServletContextListener

Comment: By services you mean external programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BootStrap is safer if you want to call any Grails logic such as GORM methods, `grailsApplication.config` or other Grails spring beans such as services. And if anyone else will have to maintain your code in future then BootStrap is where anyone who knows Grails would *expect* such logic to go. In addition you don't have to edit the web.xml template if you use BootStrap, whereas you would need to to register a custom listener. So to my mind BootStrap wins hands down.